# How to explain polytheistic gods in a world with a monotheistic origin

Tags: religion, mythology

My world was created by a single God who (at the moment) has no physical form.

But there are also humanoids gods with physical bodies.  They have similar powers to the creator God but they are a lot weaker.

Despite being weaker they are a little more involved then the Creator God on account they have a physical body.  The Creator God does get involved with his creation but to a lesser extent.

How can I explain polytheistic humanoid gods without creating two contradictory mythologies.

Comment: I do not understand what the problem is. There is one "Overgod." There are many lesser gods. This is a common pattern in both real-world and fictional religions and mythologies. What do you think is contradictory about this setup?

Comment: The problem here is that "god" is a broader term than many people think. You're using it in to different ways when you think of creator god vs other types of gods (which are the majority)

Answer (score 6):

There are tons of ways that this is already dealt with in a number of different religions.

Some forms of Hinduism have all the deities being [avatars or incarnations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindu_deities) of [Brahman](http://www.hinduwebsite.com/brahmanmain.asp). In Zoroastrianism [Ahura Mazda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahura_Mazda) is the supreme being with the twin spirits Vohu Manah of the good and Angra Mainyu of the bad (which Angra Mainyu created all of the minor and lesser spirits from pre-Zoroastrian worship). In Judaism there are choirs of [angels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jewish_angelic_hierarchy) (and demons). In some forms of Christianity there are not only the angels and demons but also the saints of God which have divine power. In Islam there are the [Jinn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jinn).

See also the Silmarillion by JRR Tolkien.

So the other deities can be aspects of God, they can be emanations of God, they can be powerful beings with free will that have at times claimed to be God, they can be creatures made of the unused elements in the creation of humans per the classical sense of elements, they can be the spirits of locations, they can be cast out angels; basically it is really easy to fit in such beings as part of your mythology.

Answer (score 4):

"How can I explain polytheistic humanoid gods without creating two contradictory mythologies"? By creating a mythology in which a monotheistic deity creator creates the  world with polytheistic humanoid gods as part of the mix.

The short answer is a deity did it. Sorry to say, it's that simple. Now I shall rest on the seventh day.

Answer (score 3):

I think to not have the secondary gods not originate from the mono god you need to have a generic divine force or material. Maybe this was what the mono god original formed from himself.

After the mono-god sucks up most of that material in his own creation and the creation of your world, there might be some left over. Maybe this forms into another force separate from the god (could be conscious devil, or unconcious like a storm that flutters around the universe) and acts like a catalyst introducing things outside of the mono-gods control.

Another option is maybe this divine energy is just inherently leaking and pooling into reality concentrating into some beings (the minor gods).

Your religion would include the mono-god as a creator being and supreme divine but also include the divine energies as distinct from him and allow for the minor gods to then be independent of the high god.